# Vimeo fullscreen breaks positioning

Tags: ios, embed, fullscreen, vimeo, fullpage.js

I'm experiencing an issue on iOS10 (Safari only, Chrome is perfect) which is being caused by a Vimeo embed which plays in fullscreen natively on iOS. The video plays perfectly, however when I click "Done" and the video closes it affects the positioning of the sections (website uses fullPage.js). Please see the URL below:

http://rorymstaging.wpengine.com/stack/#thestoryof2016

This doesn't seem to happen every time, but if you play the video and close it a few times you should see that the positioning is affected. The screenshot below shows the issue, obviously I'd love the video to return to the center of the screen when not being viewed:

[image]

I've tried inspecting the code to see how the positioning is being affected and have tried a few CSS only fixes but nothing seems to correct the bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Lewis.